# Найти число которое встречается больше всего раз

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Нужно найти число которое встречается больше всего раз. Выводит 3 вместо 5.
4 4 5 3 1 5 3 2 5 5
Чаще встречается число: 3

```
   var sq:=SeqRandomInteger(10,0,5);
    sq.Println;
    print('Чаще встречается число:');
    sq.GroupBy(x->x).OrderBy(x->x.Count).Last.Key.Println;
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените SeqRandomInteger на ArrRandomInteger. Нельзя мутирующую последовательность обрабатывать более чем одним проходом.